# Stripe refresh data in useElement hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

In form payment user has option to change duration of premium account (e.g from 1 month to 3 months). When user change it, front sent to api query to again create `paymentIntents`:

```
return await this.stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 2000 * months,
    currency: 'pln',
    payment_method_types: ['p24', 'card'],
    receipt_email: user.email,
    description: 'premium',
});
```

`this.stripe.paymentIntents` return data:

```
amount: 4000
client_secret: "pi_3KTDMNDbx0KEJcOR289fojfP_secret_Mh5jPfAKjvxpeZCuXmRcjilFL"
id: "pi_3KTDMNDbx0KEJcOR289fojfP"
...
```

The problem is with hook `useElements` from `@stripe/react-stripe-js` library. Inside this hook still I have old `id` and when I click "Pay" I have old amount it's 2000, should be 6000.

How I can refresh data in `useElements` when user change count of months?

PS: I'm using this [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements&html-or-react=react). Select 'Custom payment flow' and in backend I have Node (Nest.js), in front I have React.

Update:

Stripe method for payment:

```
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

const Stripe = () => {

    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()

    const sendPaymentDetails = async data => {
        if (!stripe || !elements) return
        setIsLoading(true)
        const { name, email } = data

        await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: `${APPLICATION_URL}premium`,
                payment_method_data: {
                    billing_details: {
                        name,
                        email,
                    },
                },
            },
        })
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={sendPaymentDetails}>
        <PaymentElement />
      </form>
    )
}
```

and this is method to create `paymentIntent`:

```
const [stripeOptions, setStripeOptions] = useState(null)

const paymentIntent = async months => {
  const { data } = await createPaymentIntent(months);
  setStripeOptions(data);
};
```

when I create new `paymentIntent`, should update too `useElement` data

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code you are working and have an issue with? See [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the `useElements` hook you refer to, and where is it being used?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolve.I should update paymentIntents, not create new paymentIntents. So I add method:

```
return await this.stripe.paymentIntents.update(id, {
  amount: this.amount * months,
});
```

from this [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update)

Now inside `useElements` hook I have correctly data